# regex pattern match

Tags: java, regex, string

I am using java regex library to find a pattern "String_OneOrMoreDigits". For example, "linenumber_1" or "linenumber_31" or "linenumber_456". I am trying the following pattern assuming I will get string of type "linenumber_2" or "linenumber_44". However, I just get the strings of type "linenumber_2", it does not match more than one number at the end. How to go about matching such strings?

`Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(linenumber_[0-9])|(linenumber_[0-9][0-9])");`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need for an alternation, just use a "one or more" qualifier on the `[0-9]`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("linenumber_[0-9]+");
```

That will match "linenumber_1" and "linenumber_44" and "linenumber_12345984". If you *only* want to match one or two digits, you can do that by being more explicit about the number of digits allowed:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("linenumber_[0-9]{1,2}");
```

Answer (score 2):

to add on if you want specific amount of digits, instead of

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("linenumber_[0-9]{1,2}");
```

you could also use

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("linenumber_[0-9]{1|4|8}");
```

which would specify that you want either 1 digit, 4 digits or 8 digits.
and like Crowder said,

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("linenumber_[0-9]+");
```

would match with any number of digits.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("linenumber_\d+");
```

and if you need a case insensitive match, append `(?i)` at the start like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)linenumber_\d+");
```

`(?i)` allows regex engine to perform case insensitive match.
`\d` would match any digit from `0 to 9`